# Socket.io-based app running through node proxy server disconnecting all sockets whenever one disconnects

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, node-http-proxy

I made a basic chat app using `node.js`, `express` and `socket.io`. It's not too different from the [tutorial chat app](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) for socket.io, it simply emits events between connected clients. When I ran it on port 3001 on my server, it worked fine.

Then I made a proxy server app using [`node-http-proxy`](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) which listens on port 80 and redirects traffic based on the requested url to various independent node apps I have running on different ports. Pretty straightforward. But something is breaking. Whenever anyone disconnects, **every single socket** dis- and re-connects. This is bad for my chat app, which has connection-based events. The client consoles all show:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://*[some socket info]*' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

Here's what I think are the important parts of my code.

#### proxy-server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

//create proxy template object with websockets enabled
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({ws: true});

//check the header on request and return the appropriate port to proxy to
function sites (req) {
    //webapps get their own dedicated port
    if (req == 'mychatwebsite.com') {return 'http://localhost:3001';}
    else if (req == 'someothersite.com') {return 'http://localhost:3002';}
    //static sites are handled by a vhost server on port 3000
    else {return 'http://localhost:3000';}
}

//create node server on port 80 and proxy to ports accordingly
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    proxy.web(req, res, { target: sites(req.headers.host) });
}).listen(80);
```

#### chat-app.js

```
/*
...other modules
*/
var express = require("express");
var app = exports.app = express(); //I probably don't need "exports.app" anymore
var http = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);

io.on("connection", function (socket) {
  /*
  ...fun socket.on and io.emit stuff
  */
  socket.on("disconnect", function () {
    //say bye
  });
});

http.listen(3001, function () {
  console.log("listening on port 3001");
});
```

Now from what I've read on [socket.io's site](http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/#), I might need to use something to carry the socket traffic through my proxy server. I thought that node-http-proxy did that for me with the `{ws: true}` option as it states in [their docs](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy#proxying-websockets), but apparently it doesn't work like I thought it would. socket.io mentions three different things:

- [`sticky session`](https://github.com/indutny/sticky-session) based on node's built in `cluster` module
- [`socket.io-redis`](https://github.com/automattic/socket.io-redis), which allows separate socket.io instances to talk to each other
- [`socket.io-emitter`](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-emitter), which allows socket.io to talk to non-socket.io processes

I have exactly no idea what any of this means or does. I am accidentally coding way above my skill level here, and I have no idea which of these tools will solve my problem (if any) or even what the cause of my problem really is.

<sub>Obligatory apology: I'm new to node.js, so please forgive me.</sub>

<sup>Also obligatory: I know other apps like nginx can solve a lot of my issues, but my goal is to learn and understand how to use this set of tools before I go picking up new ones. And, the less apps I use, the better.</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your intuition about needing to "carry the socket traffic through" the proxy server is right on. To establish a websocket, the client makes an HTTP request with a special `Upgrade` header, signalling the server to switch protocols ([RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-1.3)). In node, `http.Server` instances emit an `upgrade` event when this happens and if the event is not handled, the connection is immediately closed.

You need to listen for the `upgrade` event on your http server and handle it:

```
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({ws: true})
var http = http.createServer(/* snip */).listen(80)

// handle upgrade events by proxying websockets
// something like this
http.on('upgrade', function (req, socket, head) {
  proxy.ws(req, socket, head, {target:sites(req.headers.host)})
})
```

See the [node docs on the upgrade event](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_upgrade) and the [node-http-proxy docs](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy#proxying-websockets) for more.